# How to get exact value from NSNumberFormatter?

Tags: ios, swift, nsnumberformatter

From the code below I want `convertedN` to be to be `99999999` but instead I get `99999998`. The problem is that there is a rounding error before I set `n`. What can I do to get the result I want?

```
let amount = ".99999999"
let tmpFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
tmpFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 8
let n = tmpFormatter.numberFromString(amount)
let decimalAmount = NSDecimalNumber(decimal: n!.decimalValue)
let convertedN = (decimalAmount.decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy(NSDecimalNumber(unsignedLongLong: 100000000))).unsignedLongLongValue
```

Comment: Welcome to the fun world of floating point numbers! We have t-shirts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
let amount = ".99999999"
let decimalAmount = NSDecimalNumber(string: amount)
let convertedN = decimalAmount.decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy(NSDecimalNumber(string: "100000000")).unsignedLongLongValue   // 99,999,999
```

Answer (score 2):

Use doubleValue instead. `NSDecimalNumber` is rounding the numbers.

```
let amount = ".99999999"
let tmpFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
tmpFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 8
let n = tmpFormatter.numberFromString(amount)
let doubleValue = n!.doubleValue
let convertedN = doubleValue * 100000000
```

Comment: But "shouldn't" the NSDecimalNumber be more precise? Or, how to stop the rounding?

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with `NSDecimalNumber`s default behavior?

Apple docs: 
This method uses the default behavior when handling calculation errors and when rounding.

Comment: So now it works for ".99999999", but try "4.00057456" and I get 400057455.

Comment: I tried it multiplying using `Double`s only. It may be `Double`'s behavior for numbers with large size for optimization.